# скрипт для старта и остановки демона tomcat?

Tags: linux, tomcat

Добрый день. Меня интересует:
1) Имя и назначение демона(и скрипта)
2)уровни, на которых стартует и останавливается демон
3) какие конф. файлы вовлечены в использование демона?
4) какие сигналы с помощью service я могу подать демону?

Comment: а дистрибутив какой? как вы ставили tomcat?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS, я не ставил еще tomcat

Comment: добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.